# I am having a warning message below after running the script

Tags: r

Why does the following script produce the following warning?

```
portfolioPrices <- NULL
for (ticker in tickers) {
  portfolioPrices <- cbind(portfolioPrices, getSymbols.yahoo(ticker, from='2016-02-19', periodicity = 
  'daily', auto.assign=FALSE)[,4])
}
```

Warning:

```
1: 'indexClass<-' is deprecated.
Use 'tclass<-' instead.
See help("Deprecated") and help("xts-deprecated"). 
2: 'indexClass<-' is deprecated.
Use 'tclass<-' instead.
See help("Deprecated") and help("xts-deprecated").
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. This looks like something you should report to the maintainer of whichever package you are using but I suspect they are aware already. Have you updated your installed packages?

Comment: These are not functions in base R.  Please include the `library` statements in your code so that we know where to look for the functions that you use.

Comment: Hi Roland. I am using R x64 3.6.2 and RStudio Version 1.2.5033. I just installed yesterday. Do you think is compatibility issue? Thanks.

Comment: Hi G5W, i included library(quantmod), library(PerformanceAnalytics) and library (PortfolioAnalytics). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The usual suggestion is for you to provide a MWE...  We can do without here.

You can safely **ignore** these warning messages for now, **but** be aware that if the `quantmod` library maintainers do not update their package to meet changes in the `xts` library, this could stop working in the (near?) future<sup>1</sup>.
To ignore the said warnings, you can wrap your `getSybmols` calls in `suppressWarnings` if you want to keep them from being printed to the console.

Joshua Ulrich is responsible for the `xts` package and has made the change from `indexClass` to `tclass` some time back: [see this 20 April 2018 commit on GitHub](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/commit/96ecb90d69645d9b64849b9bf69da5625c08cf32)

<sup>1</sup>As an example of a well maintained package, you can see [Brian Peterson's Quantstrat package](https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat/commit/733796807d5f7253533a630c13f2f8678878357c) and how he replaced `indexClass` with `tclass`, basically addressing the warning you are seeing in `quantmod`.